# Image optimization in plain React

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

is there any opportunity to have image optimization library for React JS like Next/Image?

I tried to use react-imgix package for optimization, but it hasn’t worked. Probably it works only in Imgix server. My main goal is to have ability to use srcSet option for remote images like in Next JS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.